# Java - rounding by quarter intervals

Tags: java, math, numbers, rounding

I'm running into following issue...

Does an already 'built-in' function exists in java to round given random numbers to the closest lower quarter value.

These are the given random numbers:

```
2.00 -> 2.00
2.24 -> 2.00
2.25 -> 2.25
2.49 -> 2.25
2.50 -> 2.50
2.74 -> 2.50
2.75 -> 2.75
2.99 -> 2.75
3.00 -> 3.00
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can multiply the value by 4 then floor it then divide by 4.

```
public static double quarterRound(double v){
   return Math.floor(v*4)/4;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to round to quarters so:

- Multiply by 4
- Floor to next int
- Divide by 4

Note that if you reliable values it is better to works with **BigDecimal** instead of primitive values (`double` or `float`). The algorithm stay the same.

Comment: In this particular instance, binary floating-point may be better: multiplication by 4 and division by 4 are exact operations for binary floating-point (assuming that overflow and underflow are avoided), but might incur rounding errors for decimal floating-point.  The floor operation is also exact (for both decimal and binary floating-point).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double value = 2.99D;
value = (double)(int)(value * 4) / 4;
```