# Round up float .25

Tags: android, rounding

Hello I should round up my float value to successive .25 value.
Example:

```
0.123 =>  0.25
0.27 => 0.5
0.23 => 0.25
0.78 => 1
0.73 => 0.75
10.20 => 10.25
10.28 => 10.5
```

I tried use `Math.round(myFloat*4)/4f;` but it return the nearest, so if I have:

```
1.1 return 1 and not 1.25
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(myFloat*4)/4f`

Comment: how about use `ceil`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `Math.ceil()` instead of `Math.round():`

```
Math.ceil(myFloat*4) / 4.0d;
```

Closely related: [Java - rounding by quarter intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274898/java-rounding-by-quarter-intervals)

Comment: If I were you though I'd divide by `4.0`. The wise owls at Java decided that `ceil` should return a `double` cf. `round` returning `long`. If you had used `round` then the division would happen in integer arithmetic! *Just in case* a refactorer changes your formula to `round`, I'd doubly force the expression to be calculated in floating point.

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. To round up, use `Math.ceil(myFloat*4)/4f` instead of `Math.round`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own round off logic.

```
public static double roundOffValue(double value) {
    double d = (double) Math.round(value * 10) / 10;
    double iPart = (long) d;
    double fPart = value - iPart;
    if (value == 0.0) {
        return 0;
    }else if(fPart == 0.0){
        return iPart;
    }else if (fPart <= 0.25) {
        iPart = iPart + 0.25;
    } else if (fPart <= 0.5) {
        iPart = iPart + 0.5;
    } else if (fPart < 0.75) {
        iPart = iPart + 0.75;
    } else {
        iPart = iPart + 1;
    }
    return iPart;
}
```

Comment: A nice idea, but this can "go off" due to floating point. It's not a good idea to interchange `round`, `floor`, and `ceil` using additive constants. The accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902968/why-does-math-round0-49999999999999994-return-1 explains this well.